# Save HTTP jpeg image on computer using Delphi Prism?

Tags: .net, delphi, http, delphi-prism

I have a script written using Delphi Prism to extract specific images on webpages.

I got up to the part where i can show the image in PictureBox by simply placing the url in PictureBox.ImageLocation

How can I save this image to somewhere on my computer?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DownloadFile method from System.Net.WebClient.